# Why Post controller to upload a file is not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

```
@PostMapping("/post")

public String write(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile files, BoardDto boardDto) {

    try {
        String origFilename = files.getOriginalFilename();
 
        String filename = new MD5Generator(origFilename).toString();

        String savePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\files";

        if (!new File(savePath).exists()) {
            try {
                new File(​savePath).mkdir();
            } catch(Exception e){
                e.getStackTrace();
            }
        }

        String filePath = savePath + "\\" + filename;

        files.transferTo(new File(​filePath));

​

        FileDto fileDto = new FileDto();

        fileDto.setOrigFilename(origFilename);

        fileDto.setFilename(filename);

        fileDto.setFilePath(filePath);

​

        Long fileId = fileService.saveFile(fileDto);

        boardDto.setFileId(fileId);

        boardService.savePost(boardDto);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "redirect:/";
}
```

​

​

```
if (!new File(savePath).exists()) {

    ^

constructor File.File(Long,String,String,String) is not applicable
```

Description: I am working on a file upload project. but it's not working. File is just entity class and It's someone else's code. the guy worked fine but I'm not

Comment: Is that `File` class `java.io.File` or a custom one? 
`File.File` looks  weird

Comment: What does "*is not working*" mean?

Comment: Can you share the import line of the `File` class you are using please?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to rewrite this code using `Files` API.

For example: `...if (Files.notExists(Paths.get(savePath))) {...`

It looks like you create too many `File` objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload a file to a Spring controller using logic as follows:

Basic HTML that sends a file to a /upload controller:

```
 <p>Upload an image</p>

     <form method="POST" onsubmit="myFunction()" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="file" /><br/><br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
     </form>
    <div>
```

Here is the controller:

```
// Upload a file.
   @RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   @ResponseBody
   public ModelAndView singleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

    try {

        byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
        String name =  file.getOriginalFilename() ;

        // DO something with the file.
    
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("photo"));
}
```